# Master page- references to other files

Tags: c#, asp.net-4.0

I've got a master page in ASP.NET which references various other content such as javascript and CSS files. These are currently not in `<asp:` tags, they're in regular HTML. How can I make these references relative to whatever content page is being loaded such that they work regardless of where the content page is located within the server? The other similar questions were specific to tags which have `<asp:` equivalents or SharePoint.

Comment: I think I misread your question... isn't what you're describing the default behavior?  Unless you use a rooted path, src and href will automatically be relative to the current page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I do it:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=ResolveUrl("~/lib/jquery.address.js")%>"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" href="<%=ResolveUrl("~/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css")%>" />
```

This way, it doesn't matter where the master page is located.

Side point, as I'm sure you know, a `url()` in a css file is evaluated relative to the css file.  So when I have css files located beside their master template, any related images folders go there, too.